# Angular alert input returns 'undefined'

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to print the input value in ionic popup. But it returns 'undefined' in the console instead of the entered text in the input field. I was trying without `$scope` as well but didn't work. What might be the problem with it? Below you can see the code I use.

```
function funcNew() {
        var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
            template: '<input type="text" ng-model="description">',
            title: 'Enter Description',
            subTitle: '',
            scope: $scope,
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Cancel'
                },
                {
                    text: '<b>Yes</b>',
                    type: 'button-positive',
                    onTap: function (e) {
                        console.log($scope.description);

                    }
            }]
        });
    }
```

Comment: Does it say what is undefined in the console?

Comment: No, it just prints 'undefined' instead of the real value of 'description'.

Comment: A way to troubleshoot this would be do do a `console.log($scope)` that could give you more insight into what is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `description` use `data.description` in `ng-model` and in `console.log($scope.data.description)`

Comment: Glad to know that. Thanks!